# How to run interactive commands using python tcp socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, python-sockets

Say if I wanted to run vim ./foo.txt I want to be able to edit foo.txt with my tcp socket client.

But whenever I try to do this it executes on the server but not on my client.

I do not want to use paramiko or any other ssh-like modules I want to stay using the python socket module.

I am using python 3.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to get your keypresses on the client, over to the server, and then into vim. And to get vim's display output back to the client and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest opening a command on the server (where the file is) with the subprocess module. This way to can keep putting information into it. You can have the client send a message which tells the server to send x to the subprocess.

An example would be like this:

```
import subprocess

# Assuming the variable x is that the socket is sending the server...
editing_foo = subprocess.Popen(['vim', './foo.txt'], stdin=PIPE)  # stdin must be PIPE to communicate
editing_foo.communicate(input=x)  # input is a string which is sent to the subprocess
# x could have been 'i' or ':q!' for example
```

Comment: When I run this it says PIPE is undefined any answer?

Comment: Cool! I'm happy I could help. Check out the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation page on the Python website for more info about the module.